# Pandas dataframe split() 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a date columns like `2016-12-15`. `df["first_review"].dt` does not work (it says the column type is not datetime).

I am trying to separate manually but I have error:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'.
```

What can I do? The missing value representation is that `NaN`.

```
dates = ["first_review","host_since","last_review"]
for i in dates:
    for j in range(len(df)):
        df[i+"_year"],df[i+"_month"],df[i+"_day"] =  df.loc[j,i].split("-")
        
display_all(df["first_review_year"])
```

Comment: can you show a head of you data table

Comment: Try `print(df.loc[j,i])`, and show me the output.

Comment: the output of  print(df.loc[j,i])  is that 2017-04-30

Comment: @OğuzhanErcan What about `print(type(df.loc[j,i]))`?

Comment: thanks for your interest I have solved the problem by this line :         df[i+"_year"],df[i+"_month"],df[i+"_day"] = (0,0,0) if type(df.loc[j,i]) == float else df.loc[j,i].split("-")

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that

```
df[i+"_year"],df[i+"_month"],df[i+"_day"] = (0,0,0) if type(df.loc[j,i]) == float else df.loc[j,i].split("-")
```

The missing value type is float. The problem is based on that